# JavaScript/HTML | Making HTML paragraph equal to User Input

Tags: javascript, html, input, user-input

I'm beginner in HTML and I wanted to know, how I can make a paragraph in the HTML-Body equal to a text that the user has written into a textbox in the HTML-Body using a JavaScript function. Are there any ways to do that? And another question: What is happening, when the user clicks on a "Submit" button? Does HTML write all the input of the user into variables?

(EDIT) So, here's my code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input-text">
        <input type="user-answer" id="uA1">
        <p id="paragraph"></p>
        <input type="button" onClick="inp.input();" value="Write Text">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var inp = document.getElementById('uA1');
var p = document.getElementById('paragraph');

inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
    p.textContent = inp.value;
});
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the JavaScript function `document.getElementById()` and the `innerHTML` property for putting things in a paragraph.  When you have some code, edit your question to show us your code.  For the second part, when a form is submitted, the elements in the form are sent to the server as name-value pairs.  The name comes from the `name=` attribute of the form element, and the value is the value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking 'submit' button browser serialise content of the containing that button form to url-encoded string (`name1=value1&name2=value2&etc=etc`) and perform the http request described in the `form` tag (`action` and `method` attributes). It will not create any variables or save its. All values already saved in properties of form elements (nodes of DOM tree).

To sync your input with paragraph you have to add event listener to that input that will listen if user insert any text there and then use inputs value as text content of the paragraph.

```
var inp = document.getElementById('myArea');
var p = document.getElementById('myP');

inp.addEventListener('input', function(){
    p.textContent = inp.value;
});
```

See it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z64cv17a/).

You can see that in this example I used the property `value` of the `textarea` DOM node (selected by it's id). That's the place where the data of the form is stored but *until* you click 'submit' button.

Answer (score 0):

For the question about what happens when user click on "submit" button, generaly all the information included in your input are stored in php variable. I don't think you want to work with php, but this is as easy as it :

```
<form method = "post" action = "next.php">
    <div>
        <input id = "id" name = "id" placeholder = "your id here..." />
        <input id = "pass" name = "pass" placeholder = "your pass here..." />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id = "btn_valid" value = "Valid information" />
    </div>
</form>
```

In this example, I made a short form, with two input to let user type his id and his password. If you specified the "name" tag (like I did in the two input "id" and "pass"), you will be able to get them in your php "next.php" file like this (in another page, in this case in the page "next.php") :

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
?>
```

Because you specified to go to "next.php" in the form parameters, you will be able to get these data by calling "$_POST['name-of-the-input']". And it works for all kind of element which can have a "name" tag !

Last information, a php file can contains html, javascript, or php code ! But you need to execute it via a server (like Xampp).